# Dynamically select which partition to mount based on root partition

Tags: debian, boot, partition, fstab, systemd-mount

I have got two readonly root partitions (say roota and rootb) which operating system is installed. This is for a basic A/B partition update scheme and after updating my system these partitions are selected for boot in a roundrobin fashion.

I have two other partitions (say data1 and data2) and I would like to mount on of these partitions based on the partition I boot.

So, the scenario is like this:

I boot from roota, automatically data1 is mounted. I updated system writing updated image to rootb. I boot from rootb and data2 is automatically mounted. Again I updated system writing updated image to roota, I boot from roota and data1 is mounted... etc.

roota and rootb partitions are readonly (squashfs). data1 and data2 are rw partitions. How can I achieve this behavior in an elegant way for debian 11 bullseye?

Comment: A systemd unit which calls a Bash script.

Comment: You suggest running mount command from a bash script?

Comment: Why not? You've got any other ideas? ;-)

Comment: Just asked to verify :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what your configuration is, but the script will essentially be something like this:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

default=/dev/partition1
root=`mount | grep -w / | awk '{print $1}'` # verify this works for you
test "$root" = "partitionB" && default=/dev/partition2
mount $default /mnt/somewhere
```